# PhotogrammetrySession on iPad Fails both url input and Sample Seq input

Tags: avcapturesession, realitykit, lidar, photogrammetry, avcapturephotosettings

I'm developing a 3D scanner that works on an iPad(pro 6th generation, 12.9-inch).

I tried ObjectCaptureSession and tried Photogrammetry with HEIC pictures made from ObjectCaptureSession, which was successful.

But using manually captured picture fails and I don't know how to do.

I tried to take a picture using AVCaptureSession and put the data into the `PhotogrammetrySample` structure, but it failed.

settings are:

- camera: back Lidar camera,
- image format: `kCVPicelFormatType_32BGRA`(failed with crash) or `hevc`(just failed) image
- depth format: `kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32` or `kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32`
- photoSetting: `isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true`, `isDepthDataFiltered = false`, `embeded = true`

So.. this time, I tried with HEIC image, but it also fails.
It succeed only when the metaData is replaced with nil(`AVCapturePhotoFileDataRepresentationCustomizer.replacementDepthData` returns nil)
but it seems to be no depthData or gravity data were used for the photogrammetry

And I also tested some sample codes provided by apple:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_a_photogrammetry_command-line_app
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/capturing_depth_using_the_lidar_camera
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/taking_pictures_for_3d_object_capture

What should I do to make Photogrammetry successful?